# Rotate scnnode with velocity

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have an `scnnode` that I rotate with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` around it's Y axis. This is great, but I'd like to apply inertia to the avatar so it keeps spinning (and slows down) once the user lifts their finger, kinda like what you have with a scrollView. Is this possible?

```
   func addMoveAvatarGestures(sceneView: SCNView) {
        let pan = gestureWithRootNode(target:self, action:#selector(rotateAvatar(_:)))
        if let scene = sceneView.scene {
            pan.rootNode = scene.rootNode
        }
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        pan.delegate = self
        self.rotationGesture = pan
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func rotateAvatar(_ sender: gestureWithRootNode) {

        guard let nodeToRotate = sender.rootNode else {
            return
        }


        let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view!)
        let xToAngle = Float(self.view.frame.width) / Float(360)
        let newAngleY = Float(translation.x) * xToAngle
        let velocity = sender.velocity(in: sender.view!)
        if (fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y)) {
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view!)
            nodeToRotate.eulerAngles.y += nodeExtensions.deg2rad(newAngleY)
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you solve this one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [applyTorque](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514752-applytorque) for this which changes the node's angular momentum.

It affects the node's [angularVelocity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514770-angularvelocity). You can constrain or restrict this effect by setting the [angularVelocityFactor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514748-angularvelocityfactor).